# In a django model, I want to do a table lookup for a list of column values to use as choices in one of my fields. Is it possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The model I'm trying to pull values has a different primary key than the column I'm trying to get the list from.

EDIT:  Adding a bit more detail about what I want to do:  I want to get a list of all records from CustomerCatalog that have the same value in it's "ccname" field as the Server model/form has in it's "account" field.  This way, as I'm adding a server for a specific account, it will look up all products in the CustomerCatalog that are for this specific account.

This is what I was thinking but it doesn't work:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing list of servers per contract
    """
    os_license = models.CharField(max_length=95, blank=True, choices=product_list)
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


    @staticmethod
    def product_list():
         return CustomerCatalog.objects.filter(account=Server.account).values_list('ccname', flat=True)
```

Here's the CustomerCatalog model:

```
class CustomerCatalog(models.Model):
    """
    Model for representing products that have been sold and are being used by a specific customer.
    """

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ccproductid = models.ForeignKey('ProductCatalog', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Product ID")
    ccname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Product name", blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Account to which this product was sold.')
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Unit of measurement.', null=True, blank=True, default='VM')
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter price per unit.", null=True, blank=True)
    total_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter quantity.", null=True, blank=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter total price (note this will be calculated in a future release).", null=True, blank=True)
    in_contract = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    @property
    def get_ccname(self):
        return self.ccproductid.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ccname = self.get_ccname
        super(CustomerCatalog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customer Catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return f'{self.ccname}'
```

Here's the ProductCatalog.  This is used as the unique list of all products and what is indexed when assigning products to individual customers.

```
class ProductCatalog(models.Model):
    """
    Model to represent the full product portfolio.
    """


    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Enter Product ID.", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Enter name of resource unit that will be used with service definitions.", unique=True)
    billing = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="Enter billing type.")
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text='Unit of measurement.')
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the description of the service.", blank=True)
    version = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, help_text="Enter date of the CPS version.")
    servicecat = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Enter the service in which this product belongs.')
    org = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Enter organization providing the service.")
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return f'{self.id}'
```

Comment: What does not work? Furthermore `Server.account` will indeed not work... Can you share the `CustomerCatalog` model?/

Comment: What is `Server.account`? Also, please indent it.

Comment: ERRORS:
ServiceCatalog.HistoricalServer.os_license: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
ServiceCatalog.Server.os_license: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.

Comment: Sorry, I've made some updates.  Server.account is there now.

Comment: @scharette: it is the attribute of the `Server` model, so an `models.ForeignKey(..)` instance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, it wasn't included initially.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the error log you provided:

> ERRORS: ServiceCatalog.HistoricalServer.os_license: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples. ServiceCatalog.Server.os_license: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.

method `product_list` *** returns flat list of values but not the tuples. It Should look like `tuple(tuple(value, human readable name))`. So edit this function to return tuple of these tuples. You can achieve this by mapping the flat array and adding some values to it or by taking exactly two values from `values_list` method. *(NOTE: you cannot use `flat=True`, it is prohibited and not desired).*

* `product_list` this method is not working because, you are not passing either intance nor anything else to this method. So `Server.account` is not the model instance but model class. You should edit this function for example like this.

```
def product_list(self):
     return CustomerCatalog.objects.filter(account=self.account).values_list('os_license', 'ccname') # or map(lambda x: (x, 'Some human readable string'), ...values_list('ccname'))
```